# Order By Lowest Value in total column, by year with GROUP BY on another column

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

My Table looks like the following:

[image: wp_infraexchange_market_pivots table]

Am using the following query to output this data in a table (front-end):

```
SELECT developer, GROUP_CONCAT(year) AS years, GROUP_CONCAT(total) AS totals, SUM(IFNULL(total, 0)) AS totals_sum
    FROM wp_infraexchange_market_pivots
    WHERE market_id = 2
    GROUP BY developer
    ORDER BY totals_sum DESC
    LIMIT 20;
```

This gives me output that looks like this:

[image: query result]

However, I need to output the same data, but the rows ordered by lowest total in a given year.  So, if I want to get the results ordered from lowest `total` column in the year 2012, and order it in ASC order, how can I do this in a MySQL query?  Is this even possible?

@scais - Have tried your answer, but am getting the following results:

[image]

This looks very close to what I need, cept I still need the `GROUP_CONCAT` to work.

Ok, so switched to a CASE statement in the SELECT and it almost acts properly...

```
SELECT developer, GROUP_CONCAT(year) AS years, GROUP_CONCAT(total) AS totals, SUM(IFNULL(total, 0)) AS totals_sum, 
CASE WHEN year = 2013 
    THEN total 
    ELSE NULL 
END AS year_total
        FROM wp_infraexchange_market_pivots
        WHERE market_id = 2
        GROUP BY developer
        ORDER BY year_total ASC
        LIMIT 20;
```

The above outputs the correct order and data for `2012` year, but if I change it to `2013` I don't get the correct order.  Not sure why though.  But the order is flawed and when I change it to 2015, 2016 also, it does not return the right order.  Only returns the right order for the year 2012.  I think what is happening here is that it returns right data only on first year it finds, than all other years, it returns NULL, and this is messing with the order of years that are greater than 2012 (the lowest year), but not sure how to fix this.

Here's a pic of what I'm trying to achieve with this query, where you can click the header of each column and have it ordered in ascending or descending order by year:

[image]

Comment: Handle issues of data display in application code

Comment: I'm already handling data display in application code, this was an ordering issue that MySQL is capable of outputting.  Cheers :)

Comment: I'm well aware of the limits and capabilities of MySQL, thanks. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I apologize for not providing an MCVE, but the question seemed very straightforward to me and providing an MCVE with the means that is currently out there, is extremely limited and is a bit crude in setting up what should be a simple way to get your point across.  Yes, it's better than not doing anything, but I provided pics, an explanation, and expected result.  Not sure why a sqlfiddle should be mandatory either.  Anyways, I've answered my own question, which I seem to do a lot, anymore, on Stackoverflow.  Cheers :)

Comment: I can't find the word 'mandatory' in the linked answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but I figured it out this way and works like a charm:

```
SELECT developer, GROUP_CONCAT(year) AS years, GROUP_CONCAT(total) AS totals, SUM(IFNULL(total, 0)) AS totals_sum, CASE WHEN year = 2016 THEN total ELSE NULL END AS year_total
    FROM wp_infraexchange_market_pivots
    WHERE market_id = 2
    GROUP BY developer
    ORDER BY MIN(year_total) ASC
    LIMIT 20;
```

This sorts the results (keeping developers unique) in ASCENDING ORDER all `total` from lowest to highest in the year 2016.  Now I can just simply remove 2016 and put in any year, and if I want to get highest to lowest, I just change `ORDER BY MIN(year_total) ASC` to `ORDER BY MAX(year_total) DESC` and all is PERFECT!

Guess, a `CASE` statement was needed here!  Thanks for all of your efforts guys!

Comment: Either include the CASE within the GROUP BY, or include some kind of aggregating function on the CASE clause - otherwise you're returning an indeterminate value

Comment: The solution above that I posted works as expected and returns the query in the correct order.  I still need the results grouped by `developer` only.

Comment: We have differing expectations of perfection.

Comment: This has nothing to do with perfection.  It's just a simple `order by` wall that I hit.  To each their own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT developer, GROUP_CONCAT(year) AS years, GROUP_CONCAT(total) AS totals, SUM(IFNULL(total, 0)) AS totals_sum
    FROM wp_infraexchange_market_pivots
    WHERE market_id = 2
    GROUP BY developer
    ORDER BY totals_sum DESC, years ASC
    LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: I need to order by the `total` column if given a year to get the lowest `total` from.  I don't think the year is what I need to order by, but maybe I'm wrong in this thought.  I'll test this now though, just to be sure.

Comment: @Solomon-Closson Just change the `years` for the column that you wish to order...

Comment: No, the output is no good.  I still need data as I had it, I just need the rows ordered by the lowest `total` values in `2012` year in ascending order.

Comment: @SolomonClosson so you just change the order of the `ORDER BY` this way: `ORDER BY years ASC, totals_sum DESC `. Then the ordenation's priority is for the column **years** and de second priority for the **totals_sim**.

Comment: I don't need `totals_sum DESC`.  That was just an ordering example.  I need it ordered by a year that I indicate, from lowest to highest or highest to lowest (whichever) from the `total` column for that `year`.  None of your answers do this.  Even my `CASE` statement answer is a bit flawed.

Comment: @SolomonClosson Oh man! How stupid I am!!! I'm sorry! I read your question again now... Have you tried to `GROUPBY years, developer`?

Comment: I can NOT group by `years` as it throws an error.  If I group by `year, developer` it works better, but now I'm only getting 1 year returned.

Comment: Thank you, but I finally figured it out with my answer.  +1 for you attempts though.

Answer (score 1):

could be you need  an order for years and min(total)

```
    SELECT developer, GROUP_CONCAT(year) AS years, GROUP_CONCAT(total) AS totals, SUM(IFNULL(total, 0)) AS totals_sum
    FROM wp_infraexchange_market_pivots
    WHERE market_id = 2
    GROUP BY developer
    ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(year), min(total),  totals_sum DESC
    LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: This looks like it is ordering it properly, however, I wonder if I can order it with a year that I put in instead?  Also, seems the `GROUP_CONCAT` is now not working.  Edited answer to show you the result.  Possible to keep the `GROUP_CONCAT` working?  If more columns are returned, that is fine with me, as long as it can maintain the other column values.

Comment: I have slightly change the asnwer .. not using alias  .. but directly group_concat in order by .. let me know ... the query should show the group_concat(year) and not a single year  this is weird

Comment: Updated Question, I do believe a `CASE` statement is needed now.  But my case somehow only works for `2012` year, and not other years.

Comment: Possibly need to do a GROUP on the column in the case or something?

Comment: Thanks, but I figured it out finally, posted it up as the Answer.  +1 for your attempts.  Cheers :)